# Why clojure-clr can use Console/WriteLine but can't use Task/Delay

Tags: clojure, clojureclr

I want to try clojure-clr

This program works fine:

```
(import [System])
(defn -main [& args]
 (Console/WriteLine "Hello, World!"))
```

but when I want to use Task class:

```
(import [System.Threading.Tasks])
(import [System])

(defn -main [& args]
 (Task/Delay 1))
```

I got error:System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find static field: Delay

but in this case,Task/Delay is same to Console/WriteLine

I don't know why

Comment: `Task/Delay` accepts two arguments: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1. Could this be a cause of a problem?

Comment: Task/Delay can accept only a int arg,I have been tried in my c# program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one works because `System` is loaded by default.

Try import static:

```
user=> (import (System.Threading.Tasks Task))
user=> (Task/Delay 1)
#object[DelayPromise 0x1554b35 "System.Threading.Tasks.Task+DelayPromise"]
```

Or use fully qualified name

```
user=> (System.Threading.Tasks.Task/Delay (TimeSpan/FromSeconds 10))
#object[DelayPromise 0x223ef57 "System.Threading.Tasks.Task+DelayPromise"]
```